# Retrieve the string used to define a regex pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Let's consider the variable `pattern = re.compile(r"\w+")`. Is there a way to retreive the string `r"\w+"` used to define `pattern` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- pattern.pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\w+")
>>> pattern.pattern
'\\w+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, [if we look at the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), we see that [regex objects have the attribute](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.pattern):

> `regex`.**pattern**
>
> > The pattern string from which the RE object was compiled.

Comment: You're totally right. I did not look at the right place. I was looking for something like representation rather than this.